# C# webfroms Display Image by URL path

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have stored image path in database. So to display in  tag i retrieve the Path from database and store it in variable. Once retrieved I have added the variable in img source tag. But the image isn't displaying. Need help.

```
 string imageurl = reader.GetString(10);
```

And HTML Back End

```
 htmlStr += "<tr><td>" <img src=\""+ imageurl + "\" width=\"400\" height=\"400\"></td></tr>";
 Labelbody.Text = htmlStr;
```

Consider Image path as

c:\users\vibha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\admin\admin\Profilepic\abc.jpg

Comment: What does the HTML look like when you view source in the browser? Is the path to the file right? When you watch the network traffic, does it attempt to get the file? What is the HTTP status code on the response? There's a lot more debugging you can do yourself to determine what's going wrong here.

Comment: @mason The path is correct . Its working if i do a simple HTML code to display image

Comment: That doesn't answer everything I asked in the previous comment. What does the HTML look like when you view source? And you know that a path like `C:\blah blah` is only relevant to your computer? That's not going to work on someone else's computer.

Comment: @mason Well output is Table that contains Name , Address and photo . Name and address is displayed correctly only Image is not. I have called <img> tag inside a table . i am ruining it locally.

Comment: Do you know how to view source in the browser? To see the rendered HTML? The reason I keep asking you to do that is that a Label doesn't simply just display the string that you set to its text property. That's a security feature. Read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label(v=vs.110).aspx). Putting an HTML tag in it simply won't work. You'd be better off using a Literal control. Or even better, an Image control.

Comment: @mason </td><td> <img src="C:\Users\vibha\Desktop\admin\admin\Profilepic\pc-185837_1280.jpg" width="400" height="400">  </td><td>  This is what view source is displaying .. which works fine for simple HTML code. I would like to avoid Image Control

Comment: Use a Literal instead of a label. And for goodness sakes, don't use a path off your C drive. Put the images in a sub folder of your web site and use a relative path to them.

Comment: @mason OK suree